# building monodoc for mono-addins for monodevelop missing Mono.GetOptions

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am trying to build monodevelop so that I can use F#. Monodevelop apparently requires mono-addins which requires monodoc which requires Mono.GetOptions which no longer exists.

I see a post saying that mono-2.2 had monodoc included. But, I need to build mono-3.2.3 or a version 3 mono and I think there is no monodoc included.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ack. I misunderstood an error message. monodoc is included in mono-3.2.3...